# Filter list based on peewee query

Tags: python, peewee

Given the following model:

```
class User(BaseModel):
     name = peewee.CharField()
```

and a list of names:

```
names = ['Laurence', 'Emily', 'Rose', 'Chris', 'Isaac']
```

how can I filter such a list based on if a `User` exists in the database with a name equal to any name in the list, but without having to make a query for each element in the list? For example, if users with names *"Laurence"* and *"Rose"* existed, how could I filter my list of names to `['Emily', 'Chris', 'Isaac']` without doing something like:

```
[name for name in names if not User.select().where(User.name == name).exists()]
```

Comment: Could you make a set of the preexisting names and then check whether the new name is in the set of preexisting names?

Comment: Ew no, no no. Bad idea and terribly inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
matching_users = User.select().where(User.username.in_(names))
names_present = set(user.username for user in matching_users)
absent = set(names) - names_present
```

Comment: Using sets, this is a matter of subtraction...sorry, I assumed that was clear. Edited code